# Mocking/Stubbing/unit testing mysql streaming query rows node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have a following function which uses [streaming-query-rows](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#streaming-query-rows) of mysql node js module. How can i unit test the below function and also i want to mock the database behavior instead of connecting to database while unit test.
'processRow' and ''wirteCsvFile'' function both are synchronous task.

```
function executeTask(sql_connection,sql_query) {


 let query = sql_connection.query(sql_query);
 let showInfo = {};
 let showids = [];
 query
 .on('error', (error) => {
   console.error(`error executing query --> ${error}`);
 })
 .on('result', function (row) {
   sql_connection.pause();
   processRow(row, showInfo, showids, function () {
     sql_connection.resume();
   });
 })
 .on('end', function () {
  showids.forEach(showid => {
    if (showInfo[showid].faults.length === 0) {
      delete showInfo[showid];
    }
  });
  wirteCsvFile(showInfo, (error, done) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.log("done");
      process.exit();
    }
  })
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm thinking is we can mock the `sql_connection` with a class of Event Emitter.

```
const sinon = require("sinon");
const assert = require('assert');
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const src = require('....'); // your source file that contain `executeTask`

// Create mock emitter
class QueryEmitter extends EventEmitter {}

describe('test execute task', function() {      
  const queryEmitter = new QueryEmitter();

  // we build mock connection that contains all methods used as in `sql_connection`
  const conn = { 
    query: sinon.stub().returns(queryEmitter),
    pause: sinon.spy(),
    resume: sinon.spy() 
  };

  const query = 'SELECT *';

  before(function() {
    src.executeTask(conn, query);
  });

  it('calls query', function() {
    assert(conn.query.calledWith(query));
  });

  it('on result', function() {    
    queryEmitter.emit('result');    
    assert(conn.pause.called);
    // assert if processRow is called with correct arguments
    // assert if conn.resume is called
  });

  it('on end', function() {    
    queryEmitter.emit('end');    
    // assert if writeCsvFile is called
  });

  // probably is not needed since you only call console.log here     
  it('on error', function() {        
    queryEmitter.emit('error');
  });  
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks let me try it out. Will let you know

Comment: Hi thanks for you help. your solution worked pretty well. but i am trying to add a spy on 'processRow', but unable to add it. Even if i export a processRow function and than add aspy to it is not working. How can i spy processRow?

Comment: @AkashPatel can you share your processRow code implementation?

Comment: function processRow(row, showInfo, showids, cb) {
  let showid = row.showid;
  //some more variable assignmetns

  if (isNaN(episode_num)) {
    episode_num = '';
  }

  if (showInfo[showid]) {
    //sync tasks

  } else {
    //sync tasks
  }
  cb();
} .............there aren't any async task or and other function calls it only has some calculations and conditional logic.

Answer (score 2):

You can stub the `query` function to return whatever you want instead of making request to database:

`sinon.stub(connection, "query").callsFake(() => /* whatever you want here */);`

You should also break `executeTask` into smaller functions, for ex:

```
function errorHandler(error) {
    console.error(`error executing query --> ${error}`);
}

function resultHandler(data, row) {
    sql_connection.pause();
    processRow(row, data.showInfo, data.showids, function() {
        sql_connection.resume();
    });
}

function endHandler(data) {
    data.showids.forEach(showid => {
        if (data.showInfo[showid].faults.length === 0) {
            delete data.showInfo[showid];
        }
    });

    wirteCsvFile(data.showInfo, (error, done) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } else {
            console.log("done");
            process.exit();
        }
    })
}

function executeTask(sql_connection, sql_query) {
    let query = sql_connection.query(sql_query);
    let data = {
        showInfo: {},
        showids: [],
    };

    query.on('error', errorHandler)
    .on('result', resultHandler.bind(null, data))
    .on('end', endHandler.bind(null, data));
}
```

Now you can test `errorHandler`, `resultHandler`, `endHandler` separately

Comment: Thanks let me try it out. Will let you know